# Difference between %d and %.d in C language

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I wrote the following code and received a **blank output**:

```
int main(){

    int y=0;

    printf("%.d", y);

    return 0;
}
```

Instead, If I use only `%d`, I get `0` as the output.

What is the difference between `%d` and `%.d`.

Your suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `.` before the conversion specifier is called the "precision". From the [printf man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) (emphasis mine):

> An optional precision, in the form of a period ('.') followed by an optional decimal digit string. Instead of a decimal digit string one may write "*" or "*m$" (for some decimal integer m) to specify that the precision is given in the next argument, or in the m-th argument, respectively, which must be of type int. **If the precision is given as just '.'**, or the precision is negative, **the precision is taken to be zero. This gives the minimum number of digits to appear for d, i, o, u, x, and X conversions**,

and

> d, i
>
> The int argument is converted to signed decimal notation. The precision, if any, gives the minimum number of digits that must appear; if the converted value requires fewer digits, it is padded on the left with zeros. **The default precision is 1. When 0 is printed with an explicit precision 0, the output is empty**

So for the example code, `%.d` means an integer conversion with zero precision. Zero precision means a minimum of zero digits. Since the value to be converted is `0` it is not displayed at all due to the zero precision. In contrast, `%d` has no explicit precision and hence defaults to a precision of one resulting in printing `0`.